# How to code bash script to allow entire commands with spaces?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

So basically, I'm looking for a way to make the below bash script work without an issue.  Each of the commands actually works when tested individually, it's only in the actual script it has a problem.  The code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

answer="$(/usr/bin/grep "PermitRootLogin yes" /etc/ssh/sshd_config)"

  if [ $answer ]; then
       (perl -pi -e \'s/\"PermitRootLogin yes\"/\"PermitRootLogin no\"/g\' /etc/ssh/sshd_config)
 else
    echo "Root login is already not permitted, no values changed."
fi
```

Here's what happens when I try to run it:

```
test.sh:  line 9: [: PermitRootLogin: unary operator expected
Root login is already not permitted, no values changed.
```

So basically, rather than it doing the find/replace as I want it to on the file via the perl command, it's trying to interpret it as a separate instruction.

All it is attempting to do is look at the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and then change the relevant entry from yes to no if the "answer" is found to be yes.

I'm basically looking for a way to make this work.  I've looked at a lot of bash examples on this site but none of them seem to cover this specific case.

Also, the reason I'm using `perl` is that `sed` works very oddly on Solaris 11, or isn't installed on extremely old versions, and `perl` is installed on every version from 8 forward.

Any ideas?

Comment: You've got an answer on the problem with the `[` test command.  FIxing that will show problems with the Perl.  There's no obvious reason for using a sub-shell.  And the quoting is bizarre and won't work.  You need something like: `perl -pi -e 's/"PermitRootLogin yes"/"PermitRootLogin no"/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config` (which assumes that the double quotes appear in the config file; if they don't, simply remove the double quotes from the command line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quote the variable in square brackets.

```
if [ "$answer" ] ; then
```

Otherwise, it's expanded and word-split, but `[` doesn't know what to do with two words (it expects the first one to be a unary operator like `-f` which is what the error's telling you).

Comment: That's one problem; the `perl` command is a mess too, though (but the code hasn't run into that yet — and won't until this is fixed).

Answer (score 1):

Value of `$(grep...)` is the lines found by grep or empty string. Using those lines as  argument to `[` is not too useful.

Try

```
if /usr/bin/grep "PermitRootLogin yes" /etc/ssh/sshd_config >/dev/null; then
```

instead.

How does it work?

The actual syntax for `if` in bash (or sh, for that matter) is

```
if command args; then
```

When you use `if [ ... ]` syntax, all you do is use `[` as an alias for `test` command (try running `which [` on your machine).

`if` takes the `then` branch when command succeeds (has exit code of 0) and `else` branch when it fails - returns non-zero exit code.

grep succeeds when pattern is found, fails when not found.

Comment: You can use `grep -q` instead of the redirection.

Comment: Assuming Solaris `grep` supports that option. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could just run the replace, because if it's not necessary, it won't match and it won't do anything.

This is exactly as efficient as `grep`ing the file first.

If you need a message, how about counting whether it actually did it:

```
perl -i.bak -pe '$result += s/PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/; END { exit 1 unless $result }' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

(Then test `$?` in your script).

Or:

```
perl -i.bak -pe '$result += s/PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/; END { print "Fixed permissions\n" if $result }' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```